# Bounded clique width graphs vs parameter clique width

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I am Balchandar Reddy, a research scholar. I am currently working on the parameterized complexity of a problem for the parameter clique width. The problem is known to be polynomial-time solvable on graphs with bounded clique width; does this indicate that the problem is FPT for the parameter clique width? Similary, if the problem is linear-time solvable on graphs with bounded clique width, does this indicate the same? Please clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily, being polynomial-time solvable for graphs with bounded clique-width means that on graphs of clique-width less than $k$ an algorithm solves the problem in $O(n^{f(k)})$ time for some function $f$, so it only implies that the problem is XP (slice wise polynomial) with respect to clique-width.

On the other hand if the problem is linear-time solvable on graphs with bounded clique-width, then an algorithm solves it in $O(f(k)\cdot n)$ for graphs with clique-width at most $k$, so it is indeed FPT, as FPT means being solvable in $O(f(k)\cdot n^c)$ for some function $f$ and $c>0$.